# Create table script shortcut in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Just like generating a script for a stored procedure using `sp_helptext`, do we have any short cut to generate the script for a table?

I am aware that we can right click on a table and generate a script. But I am looking for something like SP_Helptext.

Is it possible in SSMS?

Comment: In Azure Data Studio, one can select the proc name and peek the definition or go to the definition with a right-click (or alt-F12 and F12 shortcut keys). I don't think SSMS has this ability out of the box.

Comment: SSMS can retrieve the definition for a routine -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/scripting-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

> Just like generating the script for the stored procedure, we have a
>   shortcut SP_Helptext,
>
> Do we have any short cut to get create table script?

Nope.